# Print html through JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I wish to print a document by passing custom html code.

The non-working code I have written :

```
function Clickheretoprint()
{
  var disp_setting="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,"; 
      disp_setting+="scrollbars=yes,width=780, height=780, left=100, top=25"; 
  var content_vlue = document.getElementById("result_tbl").innerHTML; 

  var docprint=window.open("","",disp_setting); 
  docprint.document.open(); 
  docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>Ashley Mattresses</title>'); 
  docprint.document.write('</head><body onLoad="self.print()"><center>');          
  docprint.document.write('<TABLE width="100%" cellpadding=10 align=center  valign="top"><TR valign="top"><TD width = "33%" valign="top">col1</TD><TD width = "33%" valign="top">col2</TD><TD width = "33%" valign="top">col3</TD></TR></TABLE>');     
  docprint.document.write('</center></body></html>'); 
  docprint.document.close(); 
  docprint.focus(); 
  docprint.close();
}
```

This is the method I called on href of an anchor tag, but the not getting the work done:

```
<a href="javascript:Clickheretoprint()">
```

I am a beginner to JavaScript/jQuery coding.

Comment: OH NO IT IS URGENT? What is not working? Is there errors in the console? Do you know it is possible to print only certain things on a page without a new window. Look into CSS Print Media.

Comment: @epascarello ya i rechecked with little modifications and found to be working in firefox and not in google-chrome. Earlier I was testing on chrome itself so wasn't able to get print. But also the requirement is with chrome browser only, can you please suggest me the way-out ?
Also, thanks for the suggestion for CSS Print Media, it's great and will definitely require this for the feature.

Comment: Answer #2 is correct, but you will have to add: var disp_setting = "menubar=no;status=no;toolbar=no;"; or the settings of your choice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track. Assuming `result_tbl` is the ID of element you like to print as-is, first wrap the element with a `<div>` tag e.g.:

```
<div>
    <table id="result_tbl">
        .....
    </table>
</div>
```

Then have such code:

```
var docprint=window.open("about:blank", "_blank", disp_setting); 
var oTable = document.getElementById("result_tbl");
docprint.document.open(); 
docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>Ashley Mattresses</title>'); 
docprint.document.write('</head><body><center>');
docprint.document.write(oTable.parentNode.innerHTML);
docprint.document.write('</center></body></html>'); 
docprint.document.close(); 
docprint.print();
docprint.close();
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/v7CNG/).

Working fine for me under Chrome 18:

[image: print is working]

Comment: thanks for the efforts, have checked the live test case, you have provided above, it works and prints nice through mozilla-firefox but unable to do the same with chrome, can you please recheck and suggest me the possible way-out ?

Comment: @HarsH1610 Chrome 18 here, clicking the button open the Print page of the browser just fine.

Comment: can you please check this: in chrome's print page the print button is disabled and there isn't any print-preview of the page; is it happening the same at your end ? please suggest !

Comment: @HarsH1610 see my edit for a screenshot. Maybe you changed some settings? Can you post screenshot showing what you mean?

Comment: please find my updated screenshot image, Can you guess the problem, now ?

Comment: sorry for the mishap, I have edited this answer and have added the screenshot of the same (unavailable print-preview and disabled print-button), but it wasn't getting displayed. But now have checked the same on other machines and found your link is working great with all browsers, there might be some issue on chrome at my end; so problem seems to be resolved. Sorry for the inconvenience caused and thanks a ton for the efforts. :)

Comment: @HarsH1610 you should have edited your own post (the question) not my answer. As you can see, [the community doesn't allow](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/223594) such edits. Anyway, glad it's resolved!

Comment: Thanks for the info too, I was unaware of this :)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout: http://jsfiddle.net/5Wfqr/3/

For me only source of trouble is:

```
var content_vlue = document.getElementById("result_tbl").innerHTML;
```

Do you have element with ID : "result_tbl" within your HTML?

Comment: yes i do have it, just forgot to remove its reference from this sample code, but it doesn't work although i remove this.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts its working fine with firefox but not with google-chrome browser, can you please suggest the way-out ?

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me

```
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function printPage() {

                var docprint = window.open("about:blank", "_blank"`enter code here`, "channelmode");    
                var oTable = document.getElementById("tbl");
                docprint.document.open(); 
                docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>your title</title>'); 
                docprint.document.write('</head><body><center>');
                docprint.document.write(oTable.innerHTML);
                docprint.document.write('</center></body></html>'); 
                docprint.document.close(); 
                docprint.print();
                docprint.close();
            }
        </script>
        <table id="tbl">
            <tr>
                <td> content1 </td>
                <td> content2 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value ="print" id="printButton" onclick="javascript:printPage()"/>
    </body>
```