# How to print individual row in my result using window.print

Tags: javascript, php

[image]

How to print individual row in my result using window.print, just in anchor tag i added like this print, it brings all the row in my table I want print in individual manner

Comment: is jQuery ok and could you please show an example of the generated HTML code?

Comment: jsut added last two column  only for understanding,data is coming through db? $vensql=mysql_query("select * from billing");
$sno=0;
while($rowven=mysql_fetch_array($vensql))
{
?><td align="center"><?php  echo $rowven['billdate'];?> </td>
                  <Td><a href="javascript:window.print()">print</a></Td>}?>

Comment: yes it's ok in  jquery or javascript ,but I want to get individual row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [print html through javascript / jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770042/print-html-through-javascript-jquery) you can use this code:

```
function Print() {
  var docprint = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");//new page
  var oTable = document.getElementById("result_tbl").rows.item(0); //get the 1st row by a selector
  docprint.document.open();
  docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>Ashley Mattresses</title>'); //write HEAD section
  docprint.document.write('</head><body><center>'); //write BODY tag and center tag for printing
  docprint.document.write(oTable.innerHTML); //select the TR's HTML and add it to the new page
  docprint.document.write('</center></body></html>'); //close BODY tag
  docprint.document.close();
  docprint.print();
  docprint.close();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7CNG/77/

Comment: How to bring company logo there? where to write img src tag docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>Ashley Mattresses</title>');

Comment: it is showing only first row result , how to bring the print values based on any row var oTable = document.getElementById("result_tbl").rows.item(0); //get the 1st row by a selector. here how

Comment: you can increment the to the `row you want -1`

Comment: @webResource about the image, just add an image tag in the body with `write` also